# AEM 6.5 @Reference(target = "(component.name=componentName)") Not working

Tags: java, osgi, aem

I am trying to inject an AEM component using the `target` property of the `@Reference` annotation.

This is the component that I am trying to inject.

```
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;


@Component(immediate = true, name = "myInterceptorComponent", service = {Interceptor.class})
public class myInterceptor implements Interceptor {

  public static final String COMPONENT_NAME = "myInterceptorComponent";
    
  //... some implementation

}
```

This is the component that uses it is:

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

@Component(immediate = true)
public final class anotherComponent {

  @Reference(target = "(component.name=myInterceptorComponent)")
  private Interceptor myInterceptor;
  
  //... another implementation
}
```

This is the test I am running:

```
@ExtendWith({AemContextExtension.class})
class anotherComponent Test {
    private final AemContext context = AppAemContext.newAemContext();

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.context.registerInjectActivateService(myInterceptor.class);
        this.context.registerInjectActivateService(anotherComponent.class);
    }

    @Test
    void testMethod(){
        //Test implementation
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I am getting this error:
`org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.ReferenceViolationException: Unable to inject mandatory reference 'myInterceptor' for class com.test.anotherComponent : no matching services were found.`

If I reference the component using `@Reference` without the `target` property, the test works. Unfortunately, I have more than one interceptor and the `component.name` property let me differentiate them.

Any ideas on why this is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are registering a service you need to pass additional config to specify target name.
In your case something like:

```
this.context.registerInjectActivateService(new MyInterceptor(), Collections.singletonMap("component.name", "myInterceptorComponent"));
```